# sorl-thumbnail doesn´t resize but make images blurry instead

Tags: django-templates, sorl-thumbnail

I´m trying to fix the height of each img to "x200" but the size doesn´t change. Instead as I deincrease the height it gets more and more blurry but the height doesn´t change (every image mantain its original height).

No previous StackOverFlow issues about sorl-thumbnail solve my problem.
I didn´t find any solution in https://sorl-thumbnail.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ neither.

```
{% for product in products %}
    <div class="item">
        {% load thumbnail %}
        {% thumbnail product.image "x200" as pim %}
            <a href="{{ product.get_absolute_url }}">
                <img src="{{ pim.url }}">
            </a>
        {% endthumbnail %}
        <a href="{{ product.get_absolute_url }}">{{ product.name }}</a>
        <br>  
        {{ product.price }} €
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

The syntax below gives the same result:

```
{% thumbnail product.image "200x200" crop="center" as pim %}
    <img src="{{ pim.url }}" width="{{ im.width }}" height="{{ im.height }}">
{% endthumbnail %}
```

settings.py:

```
THUMBNAIL_DEBUG = True

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    #
    'sorl.thumbnail',
]

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
```

I applied the same code in the very same way in my previous app and it worked perfectly but here have no idea what happens.